# django inheriting context variable

Tags: django, inheritance

Here is my view where I have list of news according to filter...

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
model = News
form_class = SearchForm
template_name = "single_news.html"



def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
    self.pk = pk

    self.pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from',False)
    self.pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to',False)
    self.crawlers = request.GET.get('crawler',False)


    print self.crawlers


    return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(SingleNewsView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["form"] = SearchForm#(self.request.GET)
    if self.pub_from and self.pub_to and self.crawlers:
        context["something"] = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)
    else:
        context["something"] = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)

    return context
```

And now here I have view to download the list of news queried from context["something"].

```
def CSVView(request):

response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv"'

writer = csv.writer(response)


writer.writerow([context["something"])# Here what can I write...

return response
```

Now in the def CSVView in writer.writerow I want the context["something"] form the first view. I dont know how to do it. I want to download the news in csv. Anyone have better idea? Am I doing anything wrong??

I have tried def CSVView(request,SingleNewsView): but it sayst def CSVView only takes 2 arguement 1 given error. What am I supposed to do. How can I download the news in csv format??

Comment: it seems you are missing something, if you want to 'pass' something from one view to another, use a session https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: can I do some_val = request.session[context["something"]??

Comment: I did some_val = request.session.get("something") and printed some_val. But it prints False. Why is that ?? I m not able to get value of context["something"]

Comment: You should leave out the context completely, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm commenting, you should leave out the usage of context, in this case what you need is sessions, below how your code should look:

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    form_class = SearchForm
    template_name = "single_news.html"


    def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
        self.pk = pk

        self.pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from',False)
        self.pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to',False)
        self.crawlers = request.GET.get('crawler',False)

        if self.pub_from and self.pub_to and self.crawlers:
            value = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)  
        else:
            value= News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)
        self.request.session.set("somekey",value)
        return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)


def CSVView(request):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(self.request.session.get("somekey"))

    return response
```